# Windows 7 shuts down automatically on delete key press

Tags: windows-7, virus, malware

1. Whenever i press delete button for deleting files or folder, windows
   7 forcly shuts down the system , i m not sure is this virus or any
   keyboard shortcut malware.
2. on pess key of special char ,its add some extra char also like on
   '*' it writes '*)'
3. This is making me irritate since i cannot create doc properly nor
   delete any files.
4. I have Quick heal pro and hv malware byte software, after all scanning too
   this virus doesnt stop

Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0):

2 suggestions maybe you should try:

1. Open a text editor then type something, use Delete button to check whether keyboard works correctly or not.
2. Open your antivirus or malware app, take a full scan your computer.

Comment: i hv already tryed this , noyhing works

Answer (score 0):

There are settings under Control Panel -> Power Options -> System Settings that tell it what to do "when I press the power button" and "when I press the Sleep button" and "when I close the lid". If any of those are set to tell the system to shutdown try changing them to "do nothing". It probably isn't likely, but if the delete key no longer shuts down the system, it would be an important clue. (These are single key shutdown events.)

Comment: ok i will try and let u know